# Why does this weird VB.net behavior allow assignment to a function?

Tags: vb.net, function, syntax

I have this snippet of VB.net code, and I'm trying to figure out why it's legal:

```
Class Program
    Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())

        Console.WriteLine(New wtf().TestCrazyAssignment())
        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

    Class wtf
        Public recurse As int32 = 0
        Public Function TestCrazyAssignment() As string
            TestCrazyAssignment = "this should not be possible."

            'BadAllocation = "something" 'compiler error - did not define with Dim

            recurse = recurse + 1

            Console.WriteLine(TestCrazyAssignment)

            If recurse < 10 Then
                 TestCrazyAssignment()
            End If

            Return "umm.... ok."
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

Output:

```
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
this should not be possible.
umm.... ok.
```

In my trivial example, I want to prevent infinite recursion, but you get the idea.

Does anyone have some insight as to this one? I recently hit this in production code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the legacy VB way of setting up the return value for a function.
VB makes an undeclared local variable available which is named the same as the function name.
I strongly recommend against this and instead using explicit return statements.

(If you don't exit via a standard 'Return', then the value in the undeclared variable is returned automatically).

Comment: Finally I understand why there is an `Exit Function`

Comment: "Couldn't figure out what was confusing", said the ex-VB6 programmer.

Comment: Coming back to this, I guess it's an artifact from FORTRAN, where this style of returning was used.